# Insert elements to tensor according to array of indices using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Using Tensorflow, I want to insert values into an array (X) according to the values of an index array (idx) such that each entity represented by the index has the same number of elements in the resulting array.

For example, suppose the initial array X and the index are the following

```py
X = tf.range(6) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
idx = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]) 
fill_value = -999 # value to insert
```

In `idx`, value 1 appears the most number of times (3), so I would like to fill in values in X for the missing entries of the other index values to match 3. That would mean one insertion for value 0, since it appears 2 times, and two insertions for idx value 2.

The result should be `[0, 1, -999, 2, 3, 4, 5, -999, -999]`.

I've been able to do this by using ragged tensors but, in my application, ragged tensors are not supported. For reference, this is how I do it:

```py
# solution using ragged arrays
X_ragged = tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids(X, idx)
result = x_ragged.to_tensor(default_value=fill_value)
tf.reshape(result, -1)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(9,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([ 0, 1, -999, 2, 3, 4, 5, -999, -999], # dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to code this but if you start with

```
elements, index, count = tf.unique_with_counts([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
print('Elements ',elements)
```

which gives all the data you need then the following code fills up the 'ragged' tensor with the 'filler'

> Note : I have hard-coded `if( slice.shape[0] < 4):` this. This is the
> length of the longest repeating value but you can obtain this from
> `tf.unique_with_counts` and pass it.
> I also don't account for missing values - `[0, 0, 0, 0, 2]`. But `elements` in the code above gives you what is present. So you could
> add a row of 'fillers' using a simple loop when you find a value
> missing.

```
import tensorflow as tf

fill_value = tf.constant([-999]) # value to insert
elements, index, count = tf.unique_with_counts([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
print('Elements ',elements)
values = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2]

ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32,size=1, dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False)

def fill_values(slice,i):
    slices = slice
    if( slice.shape[0] < 4):
        for j in range( 4 - slice.shape[0] ):
            slices = tf.concat([slices,fill_value],0)
            tf.print('Fill ',slices)
    return ta.write(i,slices)

def slices( begin, c, i, filler ):
    slice = tf.slice(  values,
                       begin=[ begin ],
                       size=[ c[i] ])
    begin = begin + c[i]
    tf.print('Slice' , slice)
    ta = fill_values(slice,i) # If I don't use the return value this warning is shown
    print('TensorArray ', ta.stack()) # So I print it
    # Note: The output of this function should be used.
    # If it is not, a warning will be logged or an error may be raised.
    # To mark the output as used, call its .mark_used() method.
    return [begin , c, tf.add(i, 1), filler]

def condition( begin, c, i, _ ):
    return tf.less(i, tf.size(c))

i = tf.constant(0)
filler = tf.constant(-999)
r = tf.while_loop(  condition,slices,[0, count, i, filler ])
print('TensorArray ', ta.stack())
```

Output is

```
TensorArray  tf.Tensor(
[[   3    1    4    1]
 [   5    9 -999 -999]
 [   2 -999 -999 -999]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32)
```

But `tf.RaggedTensor` is easier. Not sure why you couldn't use it.