# Categorical distribution with different number of possible outcomes for each experiment in Tensorflow Probability

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

In Tensorflow Probability, how can I write a model using a Categorical distribution where each experiment can have a different number of outcomes?

For example, suppose we have data from 3 experiments (a, b and c) where the first two had two possible outcomes and the third one had 3 possible outcomes. We have the following array for the logits defining the probabilities of each outcome

```
logits = [a_1, a_2, b_1, b_1, c_1, c_2, c_3]
```

so that the probability of ourcome 1 in the first experiment would be `exp(a_1)/[exp(a_1) + exp(a_2)]`, and the probability of outcome 2 in experiment 3 would be `exp(c_2)/[exp(c_1) + exp(c_2) + exp(c_3)]`, and so on (you get the idea).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could pad out the smaller outcome sets with -inf logits.

i.e.

```py
tfd.Categorical(logits=[[a_1, a_2, -inf],
                        [b_1, b_2, -inf],
                        [c_1, c_2, c_3]])
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. I had a similar idea but ran into problems trying to pad and reshape my data. I wrote a separate SO for that here (maybe you have a good suggestion there, too!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67238502/insert-elements-to-tensor-according-to-array-of-indices-using-tensorflow